# Find the last match of regular expression using batch command

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd

This is my C++ header file. I need to read the **last** `#define NONPROD` and set the value of the definition to %nonprod% variable. in this case %nonprod% should contains value `1`. `%file%` is the file path.

```
#if PROD == 1
    #define NONPROD 0
#else
    #define NONPROD 1
#endif
```

This is the batch script I have created. Seems something wrong with regex.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%i in (`findstr "/c:^ *#define  *NONPROD  *[01]$" /r "%file%" 2^>nul`) do set nonprod=%%i
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems there are tabs at the start of the line in the source code, your condition must include them or you can search for aproximate lines and then, as both spaces and tabs are delimiters in `for /f` command, check if the line tokens match the search condition

```dos
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%a in ('
    findstr /r /c:"^.*#define.*NONPROD.*[0-9][0-9]*.*$" "%file%" 2^>nul
') do if "%%a"=="#define" if "%%b"=="NONPROD" if "%%d"=="" set "nonprod=%%c"
```